# CakePHP website doesn't show properly on IE

Tags: internet-explorer, cakephp

I've used CakePHP to implement my project prototype which worked correctly on every browser, but after doing the magic with CakePHP, the website doesn't show properly on IE, and on other browsers like Safari, Mozilla and Chrome it shows correctly. The website is umacv.com

Regards

Answer (score 3):

A browser compatibility issue has nothing nothing to do with your back-end architecture (like CakePHP).  There are some *very rare* exceptions, but I can assure you that this is probably not the case.  You most likely have some malfunctioning JavaScript, or malformed HTML.  We would need more information to diagnose the problem.

1. First you need to determine what the problem is, exactly.  By
   "doesn't show properly" what *exactly* isn't working?  Are there
   JavaScript errors?  Is there simply a design issue, or is the layout
   broken?
2. If there are JavaScript errors on the page, you know where to start
   troubleshooting.
3. If the design is off, you probably are using some CSS features that
   are not supported by IE.
4. If the layout is wonky, you've probably got some malformed HTML.  Make sure
   you are closing all of your opened tags.

### Update:

A very quick glance at your HTML revealed some broken markup:

```
<ul>

        <li><a href="/p/termos-de-uso.html">Termos de Uso</a></li>

        <li><a href="/p/politica-de-privacidade.html">Pol&iacute;tica de Privacidade</a></li>

        <li><a href="/p/contacte-nos.html">Contacte-nos</a></li

    </ul>
```

Notice the last, closing LI element.

Comment: Thanks, but that was not the error. I just discovered the solution by myself. CakePHP doesn't like to have the HTML header included in header.ctp file. Needs to be declared directly on the layout file.

Answer (score 1):

The header.ctp file in CakePHP is somewhat a "view" - it contains the header presentation code, thus if you include the "header in header.ctp", as you said, you'd be including the header in it's self. This inclusion must be in the default.ctp layout file. (app/views/layouts/default.ctp)
  Also as Stephen said you should check your site for any validation, JavaScript of CSS errors.
You can run Validation Checks with a lot of free tools. This will not only help you lower IE problems, it will also higher your loading time.